# EF Core generates too many queries for nested data

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a simple class to represent a tree structure, defined like this:

```
public class LicenceCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("LicenceCategoryID")]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentLicenceCategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentLicenceCategoryID")]
    public virtual List<LicenceCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Then, from an ASP.NET Core controller, I simply return `myContext.LicenceCategory`, which is about as simple as it gets.

Right now, there are five records on the database: the parent (null `ParentLicenceCategoryID`), and four children for that one parent. So no massive volumes and no very deep nesting. This is the SQL that gets generated, and is as I expect:

```
SELECT [obj].[LicenceCategoryID], [obj].[Name], [obj].[ParentLicenceCategoryID]
FROM [LicenceCategory] AS [obj]
```

However, it also generates this, five times:

```
SELECT [e].[LicenceCategoryID], [e].[Name], [e].[ParentLicenceCategoryID]
FROM [LicenceCategory] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[ParentLicenceCategoryID] = @__get_Item_0
```

Notice how the first statement already contains every field you need to build the tree structure client-side. Why on earth even do the extra select statements?

I noticed that if I `Include` navigation properties, things get much worse: For three navigation properties, I wound up with 21 select statements! Most of which are just the same statement executed again and again and again. It may do so with different parameters perhaps, but there is hardly any way to make a program any less efficient. And these are five records - what will EF do when I throw our millions of transaction records its way?

Is there a way to prevent this kind of code generation, or is EF Core simply a non-starter?

Comment: Entity Framework is doing what you've asked.   First query generates the properties for the current record.   SInce you've also asked for a list of all license categories, EF generates the second query in a loop to build the virtual List<licenseCategory>  on the object

Comment: I understand that, but there is no need to do it that way. Without EF, I would run the first query and then just loop through the result client-side to match the records I already fetched. What EF is doing, is looping through the records client side and then going back to the server (with associated overheads in the network, I/O and query compilation) to fetch the exact same data, one row at a time. When working with a million or so records and hundreds of users, the difference in performance would be a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Are you using EF Core 2.1 with lazy loading activated?

Comment: Yes, 2.1. Lazy loading on and off give the same result.

Comment: Still it has to be something (bug) related to lazy loading or EF Core version, because it doesn't reproduce on 2.1.1 with no `UseLazyLoadingProxies`.

Comment: I didn't even know 2.1.1 existed. I'll test using that.